# Removing leading NewLine chars from String by regex?

Tags: java, regex, string, newline

I am new to "REGEX".And this question is training and educational for regex in java.

I try to remove leading new line chars from a string.(I know we can do this by 'trim()',but I do not want use it).I use '^[\r\n]+' as regex,like this:

```
str = "\r\n\r\ntest";
str.replaceAll("^[\r\n]+", "");
System.out.print(str);
```

I guess result will be

> test

But the result is:

```
CRLF
CRLF
test
```

As you can see,leading new line chars do not removed.Also I try '^\s' or '^\s+' as regex,but result was same.Do you know why those regexes do not match leading new line chars?

Comment: I do not know much about java but here is a generic solution: http://regex101.com/r/sP3wW6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A String cannot be modified: replaceAll returns the changed string.

```
str = str.replaceAll(...);
```